# UITextView dynamically add color to a particular character when typed

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

My requirement is, I need to highlight the character '#' in red color when typed in my UITextView at runtime. I know this is possible with NSAttributedString and writing the logic in "shouldChangeTextInRange".I am not good at the concepts of NSAttributedString.

Please, Can anyone help me with the logic.

Comment: Just by reading the question I can tell that you have tried nothing. How will you able to accomplish something without even trying? Even I know that answer to this I will not help you. Life isn't that easy..

Comment: Post the code that you already have.

Answer (score 1):

UITextView has a property "typingAttributes" which allows you to change the attributes when required. You can make the below code memory efficient by taking a bool if required.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    normalAttrdict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor brownColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
    highlightAttrdict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor redColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
```

}

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"#"]) {
        textView.typingAttributes = highlightAttrdict;
}
else{
    textView.typingAttributes = normalAttrdict;

}

return YES;
```

}